# getting rid of concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a small problem in java. I am trying to loop through an ArrayList and add more items to the same arraylist during the looping and am getting concurrentModificationexception. what are the work-around for this problem, my code is like this

ArrayList "Errors" is already populated.

```
ArrayList<MainErrorObject> errors;
ArrayList<MainErrorObject> newList;

for (MainErrorObject current : errors)
{
   newList = processErrorObjects(current);
   errors.addall(newList);
}
```

When i try to execute the code above, i get the concurrentmodification exception. please help me in resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pattern for this is to add to a temporary list and add that list to your original after your iteration is done.

Comment: Sry, but your code style & layout is horrible. I'm going to adjust this.

Answer (score 3):

you can't iterate & modify the same collection. So have a temporary ArrayList and copy the content to main list when iteration is done.

```java
ArrayList<MainErrorObject> tempErrors;
for (meObject : Errors) {

  newList = processErrorObjects();
  tempErrors.addAll(newList);

}
errors.addAll(tempErrors);
```

**Ps:** follow the java naming conventions

Comment: Please use accepted Java naming conventions and tell OP to do the same.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can't blame OP as I am coding in c# these days, so it wasn't on top of my head right now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Iterator` class and use the `add()` method from `Iterator`, like this:

```
ListIterator<MainErrorObject> it = Errors.listIterator();
MainErrorObject me = null;

while(it.hasNext()) {
   me = it.next();
   if (//condition)
       it.add(item);
}
```

which will never throw such an exception because it's smart enough to handle said concurrent modifications.

Source: [ListIterator javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

Comment: The OP is trying to add elements to the list not removing elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

> To avoid java.util.ConcurrentModificationException exception, we can add an item through the iterator of list

```
for (ListIterator<MainErrorObject> itr = Errors.listIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
      newList = processErrorObjects(itr.next());
      for (MainErrorObject obj : newList) {
          itr.add(obj);
      }

}
```

Comment: hi @Prabhekar , when i use the list iterator , its not looping over the new items that are being added. i printed the size of Errors at the end of loop , it shows tat the new items from newList is added , but iterator is not looping over it.